# I am making a calendar app, how can I get each event to show up in different sizes depending on the length of the event?

Tags: iphone, events, uitableview, calendar, uilabel

So every calendar app out there that we have all ever used lets you add events to your schedule, and then you see a color rectangle that shows up with the event title, and it is sized depending on its length. So if an event runs from 1:00-1:45, the rectangle only takes up 3/4 of the hour slot.

Using EventKit, and EventKitUI, I have realized that making the events is going to be quite easy, now I am wondering about the next step, which is graphically making my events visible to the user.

I plan on just using a simple UITableView for my day view, so when I add an event, how could I go about representing that graphically? I am looking for some ideas on implementation here. I don't know how I could do this. Would it be a matter of making a custom label and adding it to the top of the selected cell?

I am realizing that programming is partly a problem of knowing how to do something, and the other is knowing what to do. At this point, I am struggling with the what to do part, because I think that if I had a direction, I could do it in code no problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out.

https://github.com/klazuka/Kal

I played with the sample code and threw a watch on it on gitHub because I liked what he did.  Does some calendar functions, maybe it can help you get some ideas flowing.